# lapply slower than hard coding

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I have a reasonably large `df`

```
library(data.table)

# nrows
x <- 1e7

# data
df <- data.table(group = sample(letters[1:2], x, replace=T)
                 , user = sample(1:x, x, replace=T)
                 , price = sample(1:3, x, replace=T)
                 , quantity = sample(1:3, x, replace=T)
                 ); df

      group    user price quantity
   1:     a 8286968     1        3
   2:     b 8652340     1        3
   3:     a 7388954     1        1
   4:     b 6932335     3        3
   5:     a 1468016     1        2
```

Here is the timing of the hardcode method:

```
# hardcode
system.time(
df[, .(price = sum(price), quantity = sum(quantity))
    , .(user, group)
    ][, .(mean_price = mean( price ), mean_quantity = mean(quantity))
      , .(group)
      ]
)

   user  system elapsed 
   2.77    0.28    1.41
```

vs that of `lapply`:

```
# lapply
x <- c('price', 'quantity')

system.time(
df[, lapply(.SD, \(i) sum(i))
   , .SDcols = x
   , .(user, group)
   ][, lapply(.SD, \(i) mean(i))
     , .SDcols = x
     , .(group)
     ]
)

   user  system elapsed 
  18.86    0.10   17.86
```

What could be the cause of the big run time difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `data.table` [internal optimization](https://jangorecki.gitlab.io/data.cube/library/data.table/html/datatable-optimize.html) on `mean` and `sum` isn't used due to lambda functions `\(i) sum(i)` and `\(i) mean(i)`:

> base::mean function is internally optimised to use data.table's fastmean function. mean() from base is an S3 generic and gets slow with many groups.

`lapply` isn't causing the problem as it also gets optimized:

> The expression dt[, lapply(.SD, fun), by=.] gets optimised to dt[, list(fun(a), fun(b), ...), by=.] where a,b, ... are columns in .SD. This improves performance tremendously.

```
system.time(
  df[, lapply(.SD, sum)
     , .SDcols = x
     , .(user, group)
  ][, lapply(.SD,  mean)
    , .SDcols = x
    , .(group)
  ]
)

   user  system elapsed 
   2.58    0.39    1.45
```

Comment: @Henrik, thanks again,I wasn't sure but you're right - I tested `\(i) sum(i)` + `mean` and it took 17s

Comment: I missed some comments as I saw they were removed
Were you discussing cases when e.g. `\(i) sum(i) + 1` is needed? Because any (slightly more) complex functions would require `\(i)` as `lapply(.SD,  sum+1)` would not run.
If so, what should one do?
p.s. thanks for the link to guide. I read thoroughly.

Comment: @SweepyDodo In "Expressions in j which contain only the functions min, max, mean, median, var, sd, sum, prod, first, last, head, tail ... are very effectively optimised using what we call GForce", I think "_only_" is key here. Again, please use `verbose = TRUE` to check what is going on, e.g. if GForce kicks in.

Comment: You could add an extra step after sum: `[,c(.(user=user,group=group),lapply(.SD,\(i) i+1)),.SDcols=x]`,0.2 seconds more (1.65s)

Comment: Thank you, Henrik
@Waldi but your latest suggestion would no longer be an aggregation. Am I mistaken?

Comment: It's still an aggregation: `df[, lapply(.SD, sum ), .SDcols = x, .(user, group)][,c(.(user=user,group=group),lapply(.SD,\(i) i+1)),.SDcols=x][, lapply(.SD,  mean), .SDcols = x, .(group)]`

Comment: @Waldi
I c what u mean now. Sorry, I did not understand it in its isolation earlier. Idea is to break functions apart to take advantage of GForce!
I have amended yours for slightly shorter syntax
`df[, lapply(.SD, sum )
   , .SDcols = x
   , .(user, group)
   ][, .(user=user,group=group
         , sapply(.SD,\(i) i+1))
     , .SDcols=x
     ][, lapply(.SD,  mean)
       , .SDcols = x
       , .(group)
       ]`
Much appreciated for your help, Waldi !