# data.table's GForce - Apply multiple functions to multiple columns (with optional arguments)

Tags: r, data.table

My goal is to apply multiple functions to multiple columns ***AND*** to have GForce turned on.

Say I have the below dataframe

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(fruit = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b')
                 , revenue = 1:4
                 , profit = c(2,NA,4,5)
                 ); df

   fruit revenue profit
1:     a       1      2
2:     a       2     NA
3:     a       3      4
4:     b       4      5
```

and I wanteed to apply multiple functions to multiple columns (all except `fruit`)

```
# functions
y <- \(i) {c(min(i, na.rm = T)
             , max(i, na.rm = T)
             )
           }

# apply
df[, lapply(.SD, y)
   , fruit
   , verbose = T
   ]

Finding groups using forderv ... forder.c received 4 rows and 1 columns
0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
lapply optimization changed j from 'lapply(.SD, y)' to 'list(y(revenue), y(profit))'
GForce is on, left j unchanged
Old mean optimization is on, left j unchanged.
Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ... 
  memcpy contiguous groups took 0.000s for 2 groups
  eval(j) took 0.012s for 2 calls
0.020s elapsed (0.020s cpu) 

   fruit revenue profit
1:     a       1      2
2:     a       3      4
3:     b       4      5
4:     b       4      5
```

Now, the above works!
However, notice it said `(GForce FALSE)`. So GForce was ***NOT*** on.

I think this is because, as [Waldi pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72776924/lapply-slower-than-hard-coding), when `\(i) sum(i)` is used, GForce is ***NOT*** on.
I then tried the below and passing `na.rm = T` only in `lapply`

```
# functions
z <- \(i) {c(min
             , max
              )
           }

# apply
df[, lapply(.SD, z, na.rm = T)
   , fruit
   , verbose = T
   ]

Finding groups using forderv ... forder.c received 4 rows and 1 columns
0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
lapply optimization changed j from 'lapply(.SD, z, na.rm = T)' to 'list(z(revenue, na.rm = T), z(profit, na.rm = T))'
GForce is on, left j unchanged
Old mean optimization is on, left j unchanged.
Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ... Error in z(revenue, na.rm = T) : unused argument (na.rm = T)
```

This time the error is as per above. Specifically `Error in z(revenue, na.rm = T) : unused argument (na.rm = T)`

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I don't think it will cause the optimisation to work, but you need to pass `...` as arguments to your function - `y <- \(i, ...) {c(min(i, ...), max(i, ...))}` for the `na.rm=TRUE` to be passed through appropriately.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't understand your definition of `z()`.  It appears  you omit the `na.rm` argument from the function signature, yet you still call `lapply(.SD, z,` **`na.rm = T`** `)` in your second operation.  So `lapply()` tries to pass `na.rm` to `z()`, but `z()` cannot accept it, and you get that error: _"`unused argument (na.rm = T)`"_.  This didn't fail in your first operation, because you call `lapply(.SD, y)` _without_ passing any `na.rm = T`, so it doesn't matter than `y()` also omits the `na.rm` argument in its signature.

Comment: @thelatemail You are right. `...` fixes the error but GForce is still off

Comment: @Greg The syntax is obviously incorrect. However, I got the idea from the below since it works when there is just 1 function
`df[, lapply(.SD, min, na.rm = T)]` so am just looking for the correct syntax when there are multiple functions

Comment: As far as I know, there is no correct way to do a multi-function call and keep optimisations on in a way that you would like. You can do something pointless like `df[, list(min(revenue, na.rm = TRUE), min(profit, na.rm = TRUE), max(revenue, na.rm=TRUE), max(profit, na.rm=TRUE)), fruit, verbose = T]` but that doesn't seem helpful either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `help("gforce")`:

> Expressions in j which contain only the functions min, max, mean,
> median, var, sd, sum, prod, first, last, head, tail (for example, DT[,
> list(mean(x), median(x), min(y), max(y)), by=z]), they are very
> effectively optimised using what we call GForce. These functions are
> automatically replaced with a corresponding GForce version with
> pattern g*, e.g., prod becomes gprod.

You are obviously not passing an expression containing these functions. They are hidden (to data.table's gforce optimization) inside the `y` function.

I would do this:

```
res <- df[, 
          c(lapply(.SD, min, na.rm = TRUE), lapply(.SD, max, na.rm = TRUE)), 
          by = fruit,
          verbose = T
]
#Finding groups using forderv ... forder.c received 4 rows and 1 columns
#0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
#Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0.000s #elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
#lapply optimization changed j from 'c(lapply(.SD, min, na.rm = TRUE), lapply(.SD, #max, na.rm = TRUE))' to 'list(min(revenue, na.rm = TRUE), min(profit, na.rm = #TRUE), max(revenue, na.rm = TRUE), max(profit, na.rm = TRUE))'
#GForce optimized j to 'list(gmin(revenue, na.rm = TRUE), gmin(profit, na.rm = #TRUE), gmax(revenue, na.rm = TRUE), gmax(profit, na.rm = TRUE))' (see ?GForce)
#Making each group and running j (GForce TRUE) ... gforce initial population of grp #took 0.000
#gforce assign high and low took 0.000
#gforce eval took 0.000
#0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 

setnames(res, -1, paste(names(res)[-1], 
                        rep(c("min", "max"), each = ncol(df) - 1), 
                        sep = "."))


res <- melt(res, measure.vars = measure(eco, fun, sep = "."))
#Warning message:
#In melt.data.table(res, measure.vars = measure(eco, fun, sep = ".")) :
#  'measure.vars' [revenue.min, profit.min, revenue.max, profit.max, ...] are not all of the same type. By order of hierarchy, the molten data value column will be of type 'double'. All measure variables not of type 'double' will be coerced too. Check DETAILS in ?melt.data.table for more on coercion.

dcast(res, fruit + fun ~ eco)
#Key: <fruit, dim>
#    fruit    fun profit revenue
#   <char> <char>  <num>   <num>
#1:      a    max      4       3
#2:      a    min      2       1
#3:      b    max      5       4
#4:      b    min      5       4
```

The warning is because of the different column types in `df` ("integer" and "double"). Ensure they are identical to avoid it.

Comment: so put all `lapply` in a vector `c()`. Each `lapply` is an individual function. Tested. Works. Then post processing.

I do prefer this method as it saves calling `df` multiple times (less overhead). Also has added benefit of filtering (in `i`) just once (tho not needed in original post)

Thank you, Roland

Comment: I did notice in `j` if I replaced `c()` with `.()` `data.table` then fails to utilise `GForce`. Interesting

Answer (score 1):

The only relatively simple suggestion I can give is to not try to do it inside a single `df[]` call, but rather make two separate calls to allow the optimisation to work. E.g.:

```
## bigger data example
df <- data.table(
    fruit = rep(1:2e6, each=2)
  , revenue = 1:4
  , profit = c(2,NA,4,5)
)

rbind(
    df[, lapply(.SD, min, na.rm=TRUE), by=fruit, verbose=TRUE],
    df[, lapply(.SD, max, na.rm=TRUE), by=fruit, verbose=TRUE]
)[order(fruit)]
##Making each group and running j (GForce TRUE) ... 
##Making each group and running j (GForce TRUE) ...
## About 0.13s total elapsed according to system.time()

y <- function(i) {
    c(min(i, na.rm = T),
      max(i, na.rm = T))
}

# apply
df[
  , lapply(.SD, y)
  , fruit
  , verbose = T
]
##Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ... 
##3.760s elapsed (3.770s cpu)
```

Comment: Yes, essentially unless we specify the function name ONLY, `GForce` is not used. Good to have a veteran confirm also. Thank you, latemail.
Got to admit, would have been nice if we could put multiple functions in a list (or vector) then apply them to multiple columns AND be able to pass additional argument (e.g. `na.rm = T`) AND be able to use GForce